# Построение диалога в экспертной системе

Tags: c#

Интересуют простые идеи реализации изменения GUI в зависимости от задаваемого вопроса экспертной системой. 
База содержит кучу разных вопросов, разумеется, ответы тоже везде разные. Как в таком случае подстраивать GUI под пользователя от вопроса к вопросу?
Либо нормальным будет создать в базе список допустимых ответов к каждому вопросу и выводить список на экран, чтобы пользователя вводил ответ с клавиатуры?

Comment: в чем выражается _подстройка GUI_?

Comment: @Grundy вопрос в том, чтобы не было быдлокода, и пользователю было удобно работать с GUI. направьте меня в нужное русло)

Comment: кто вам мешает динамически собирать или перестраивать GUI когда становятся известны все вводные по вопросу и ответам?

Comment: Нужно более детализировать вопрос. Он непонятен. Наведи 2-3 примера конкретной подстройки. Какое условие - как менятся гуй должен. Лишь тогда ты сможешь получить +- конкретные ответы.

Comment: @Andrew например, задается вопрос, на который можно ответить да/нет. 
в интерфейсе должно появиться нечто, чтобы можно было дать один из этих ответов. и далее по аналогии, независимо от допустимых ответов.

Comment: Экспертная система задает вопросы пользователю или наоборот? Ответ на каждый вопрос один-единственный или их может быть много? Ответ заранее известен и может быть выражен точным значением или ответы могут быть расплывчатыми, неточными?

Comment: Я так понимаю, нужно динамически создавать элементы для ввода ответов: текстбоксы - для произвольного текста, комбобоксы/радиобаттоны - для выбора одного из вариантов заранее известных ответов, чекбоксы - для выбора нескольких вариантов заранее известных ответов.

Answer (score 1):

Вам надо создать собственный язык запросов: сформировать список (группу) **существительных** (**объектов предметной области**) и список **глаголов** (возможных **действий или операций с этими объектами**) + набор возможных служебных слов типа: Как?, Когда?, Почему? и т.п.

После этого можно будет в GUI запрограммировать трансляцию запросов на основе вашего языка в язык SQL.

Answer (score 1):

создай таблицу в которой будет записано вопрос и N ответов.

N - твой максимум возможных ответвов

Когда настает черед даного вопроса - ты вытягиваешь обьект вопроса, проверяешь количество ответов где длинна ответа дольше нуля или не null(зависит от бд/ORM которые юзаешь)

Дальше одно из двух:

- под каждый из существующих ответов в обьекте генерируешь кнопку
- У тебя есть наперед N существующих кнопок изначально. И ты их скрываешь или Disable-ишь очищая Text если ответа не существует. Если ответ существует - присваиваешь в соответствующую кнопку в Text даный ответ.

Лично мне нравится больше 2й вариант. Но первый тоже неплох.

Каждая из кнопок по клику вызывает один единственный метод

```
public void AnswerButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var choosenAnswer = ((Button) e).Text;

    //делаешь запись о выбранном ответе в бд
}
```

ну и.... в принципе все.

> Либо нормальным будет создать в базе список допустимых ответов к каждому вопросу и выводить список на экран, чтобы пользователя вводил ответ с клавиатуры?

Если это экспертная система, то этот подход породит неточности. Одно и то же можно ввести разными способами, даже, если это простое Да/Нет. Только это можно записать кучей способов: +/- ; da/net ; Da/Net; Да/Нет ; да/нет ; Yes/No ; + ошибки..

Экспертная система должна работать с наперед заданными ответами, как по мне.

Comment: спасибо, уловил идею)